# Computing Chow group of a variety which is almost a blow-up of another variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

Let $X$ be a normal complex projective variety (not necessarily smooth), and let $Y$ be a smooth complex projective variety. Let $Z\subset X$ be a smooth closed subvariety. I have a morphism which is close to being a blow-up along $Z$, namely:

(*) Let $\pi : Y\rightarrow X$ be a morphism with the property that $\pi$ is an isomorphism over $X\setminus Z$, and moreover $\pi$ is a $\mathbb{P}^n$- bundle over $Z$ for some $n$.

(Note that $\pi$ may not be a blow-up if codim$Z\neq n+1$, for example.)

My question is: Can we compute the Chow groups of $Y$ in terms of the Chow groups of $X$ and $Z$?

In the case when $\pi$ is a blow-up, it has been proved in Claire Voisin's *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, Vol II*, Theorem 9.27  that such formula indeed exists, namely

> When $\pi$ is a blow-up, for each $l$, there exists an isomorphism
>
> $\bigoplus_{0\leq k\leq n-1}CH_{l-n+k}(Z) \bigoplus CH_{l}(X)\xrightarrow{\cong} CH_l (Y)$

I believe a similar result should be true for my case (*) as well, but I can't prove it. Any help or reference is welcome.

**P.S.** Actually, even knowing $CH_1(Y)$ is good enough for me for now. If even that is possible in terms of $X$ and $Z$'s Chow groups then please let me know.

Comment: I studied a fairly similar situation (on an explicit case) in an arithmetic context in my paper “Équivalence rationnelle sur les hypersurfaces cubiques de mauvaise réduction” (*J. Number Theory* **128** (2008), 926–944), §2 (specifically ¶2.6): I don't remember the details, which are tedious, but I remember that, while I couldn't find a general result that applied, it was possible (albeit tedious) to compute the maps explicitly on the explicit case at hand.

Comment: The map $\pi_*$ in your situation is surjective. Combining this with the localisation sequence on $Y$ and the projective bundle formula (for the restriction of $\pi$ to the inverse image of $Z$) gives quite a lot of information about the Chow groups. There is probably no natural map from $CH(X)$ to $CH(Y)$ though, so it seems unlikely that there is a direct sum decomposition as in the displayed formula.

Comment: There's a lot known about Chow rings of projective bundles (which is one way to establish the result for blow-ups, using the fact that a blowup is a subvariety of a projective bundle).

You could either see if a similar result is true for your situation, or perhaps try to exploit the fact that $\pi$ is a projective bundle over $Z$.